# Unity 2D Android ball jumping script AddForce

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am trying to learn the basics, I learn physics at school(ten grade).

What I have done so far - added a ball to my project and used gravity on it with `RigidBody`.

I want to make the ball jump suddenly on air when there is some touch input, for example - flappy bird.

My script is basic:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

With this script, the ball is falling(gravity) and when I touch the script, is Y coordinate changes but it happens by sudden (no animation) and it changes by like ~1 and continue falling(I can't keep the ball on screen) , also I can make it jump only once, if I press multiple times it will jump only once, as you can see here:
https://vid.me/aRfk

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created same scene in Unity3D Editor and played a little with same setup you have. And yes I had similar problems adding force on Update and also (but less) on FixedUpdate. But adding force on LateUpdate seems to work okay.

Here is my code:

```
public Rigidbody2D rb2dBall;

void LateUpdate()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        rb2dBall.AddForce (Vector2.up * 10f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

And also I turned on interpolation:

[image]

I cant say why the physics bahaves like this, could be some bug in Unity3D 5.X since on FixedUpdate it should work fine.

Comment: Check this out: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-interpolation.html

Comment: It is an incredibly bad idea to be using LateUpdate - don't do that!

Comment: Could be, but it is the result of few tries and it worked best on LateUpdate. Actually it works flawless. Just trying to hack the engine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when working with physics in Unity, it's highly recomended to use the `FixedUpdate` method, instead of the `Update`. You can check in this link http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html

The second thing is that maybe you are not applying so much force at the ball, the force needed to give a quite impulse will depends of the mass of your ball's rigidbody. So try to do something like that:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(Vector2.up * 100, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Change the fixed value `100` to adjust your needs.

Comment: I changed it to FixedUpdate and same result, so I multiplied it by 100000 instead of 100, same issue. I don't know why.

Comment: That's strange. This script is the ONLY that exists in your ball gameobject? Also, can you show how your ball's rigidbody is configured?